# Display JSON data via React Native - json array

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make an API call to grab some JSON data and display it in my React Native app, but it won't display the data to the actual app. I know that the call can work, because I am successfully calling it and logging it to the console, and I see the log - I just can't get it to display in the ReactNative portion of my code.

I think it may have to do with the fact that the JSON data has an array in it, and I'm not sure how to parse it. This is what my JSON looks like:

```
{"resultCode":0,"message":"[{\"id\":0000000,\"entityType\":\"NONE\",,\"namePrefix\":\"\",\"nameFirst\":\"\",\"nameMiddle\":\"\",\"nameLast\":\Doe\",\"nameSuffix\":\"\",\"address1\":\"1234 TEST ST\",\"address2\":\"\",\"city\":\"CUPERTINO\",\"state\":\"CA\",\"zip\":\"11111\",\"country\":\"US\",\"physicalAddress1\":\"1234 TEST ST\",\"phoneNumbers\":[],\"addresses\":[],\"email1\":\"goldtreeapparel@gmail.com\",\"gender\":\"EMPTY\",\"dob\":\"Oct 24, 2016, 12:00:00 AM\",\"occupation\":\"\",\"createdTimestamp\":\"Aug 26, 2019, 9:55:24 PM\",\"modifiedTimestamp\":\"Aug 26, 2019, 9:55:24 PM\"}]"}
```

Basically there are two fields `resultcode` and `message`, but inside `message` is an array of more JSON data. I know it's ugly, but it's just a test and it's what I have to work with.

My React Native code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor( props: {} ) {
    super(props);

     this.state = {
         isLoading: true,
         dataSource: []
     };
 }

 componentDidMount() {
     fetch("https://mytestapi.com/test.json")
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
         this.setState({
             isLoading: false,
             dataSource: responseJson
         });
     });
 }

 renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
     let { resultCode, message } = item;

     if (!message[0]) return null;
     let details = message[0];

     return (
         <View style={styles.container}>
             <Text style={styles.header}>Entity ID: {details.entityId}</Text>
         </View>
     );
 }

 keyExtractor = (item, index) => {
     return index.toString();
 }

 render() {
     return (
         <View style={{flex: 1}}>
             <FlatList
                 data={this.state.dataSource}
                 keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                 renderItem={this.renderItem}
             />
         </View>
     );
 }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      paddingTop: 45,
      backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  header: {
      fontSize: 25,
      textAlign: 'center',
      margin: 10,
     fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
});

const fetchAndLog = async() => {
   const response = await fetch("https://my.testapi.com/test.json");
   const json     = await response.json();
   console.log(json);
}

fetchAndLog();
```

I know that the call is successful, because the `fetchAndLog` function successfully logs to the console, so I'm just having an issue with displaying the JSON data in my React Native portion of the code. I've tried changing my code a few times, but can't seem to get it to print out the `message` portion of the JSON, and I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53777345/how-to-parse-json-data-in-react-native) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51107213/react-native-display-simple-json-data) to try and help.

Any tips?

EDIT: Here's the error I get when trying to view it in the app:

```
Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN

This error is located at:
  in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:632)
  in FlatList (at App.js:45)
  in RCTView (at View.js:45)
  in View (at App.js:44)
  in App (at withExpoRoot.js:20)
  in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:19)
  in ExpoRootComponent (at renderAPplication.js:35)
  in RCTView (at View.js:45)
  in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
  in RCTView (at View.js:45)
  in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
  in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

Comment: try simplifying your render function and just show the resultCode. Also, I'm concerned that this bit of code is messing the whole thing up: `if (!message[0]) return null;`

Comment: What I mean by the above comment is, I'm not sure you should ever return null. Try returning a component there instead.

Comment: Returning `null` is valid in React for a component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're passing in an object as the FlatList data source, but you should be passing an array.

Try:

```
<FlatList
     data={this.state.dataSource.message}
     keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
     renderItem={this.renderItem}
/>

...

renderItem = ({item, index}) => {

     return (
         <View style={styles.container}>
             <Text style={styles.header}>Entity ID: {item.id}</Text>
         </View>
     );
 }
```

If you're not intending on showing an array of data, you should be using something besides FlatList.  Also, I didn't see a field called `entityId` anywhere in that data.

Comment: The only reason I made it a FlatList was because of the way I had an array in the JSON - could I just change the FlatList to a Text?

Comment: If all you want to display is a single field (not an array), then sure, a `Text` is all you need.

Comment: Hmm, your fix is getting my further, it doesn't give me an error anymore, but nothing displays on the screen...can I just move my return statement from `renderItem` up into the `render` function?

Comment: yes but the code would be something like `<Text>Entity Id:{this.state.dataSource.message.id}</Text>`

Comment: So here's my new render method, I don't think it's working the same way:
`render() { return ( <View style={styles.container}> <Text>Entity ID {this.state.dataSource.message}</Text> </View> ); }`

Comment: I get an error saying `Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component`

Comment: Scratch this I got it to work! Thanks so much! I was getting the above error because I had /* */ comments in my render function, which you can't have. But your solution worked!

Comment: Okay, so now my question is, now that I have just the `message` portion of the JSON displaying, how can I access other elements within the JSON? `message.id` doesn't work - do I need to access it like an array, like `message[0].id`?

Comment: yes, since message is an array, that would be correct.  so my comment above should have been `this.state.dataSource.message[0].id`

Comment: Hmm, yeah I really don't know what's going on. When I add the `[0]` to get into the next part of the JSON array, it just says `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating this.state.dataSource.message[0].id`

Comment: I'd just `console.log(this.state.dataSource.message)` and confirm the structure is what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Is the message always present? And is the data present when coming back? I would add a couple more checks:

```
 componentDidMount() {
   fetch("https://mytestapi.com/test.json")
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((responseJson) => {
     this.setState({
         isLoading: false,
         dataSource: responseJson || []
     });
  });
}

renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
     let { resultCode, message } = item;

     if (message == null || !message[0]) return null;
     let details = message[0];

     return (
         <View style={styles.container}>
             <Text style={styles.header}>Entity ID: {details.entityId}</Text>
         </View>
     );
 }
```